# @AfterTest tearDown - Null pointer exception - selenium

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception, data-driven-tests

I am trying to create Data driven framework. 
When i run the script without tear down, the scripts runs successfully.

I tried implementing teardown() and null pointer exception is encountered.
I scripted to close the browser at the end, but still i am getting null pointer exception.

```
public class WordPressLogin {


WebDriver driver;


@Test(dataProvider="wordpressData")
public void loginToWordPress(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException
{
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\naga.priyanka\\workspace\\TestNG jars\\geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php");

    driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wp-submit']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Dashboard"), "User is not able to login-Invalid credentials");
    System.out.println("Page title verified - user is able to login successfully");

}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}

@DataProvider(name="wordpressData")
public Object[][] passData()
{
    Object[][] data=new Object[3][2];

    data[0][0]="XYZ1";
    data[0][1]="XYZ";

    /*data[1][0]="XYZ2";
    data[1][1]="XYZ";

    data[2][0]="XYZ3";
    data[2][1]="XYZ";*/

    return data;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@After should allow you to do what you are attempting when using JUnit.
@AfterTest may be failing due to the lifecycle of the webdriver being expired at that point, that tag also only works when running with TestNG.

I would recommend initializing your driver and setting up the properties in a @Before tag so that you can run multiple tests using the same driver.